# Is it possible pass promise to property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, cron

1) Can I pass a function which returns promise to parameter "onTick" in CronJob constructor?

let's say my function is:

```
`function a() {
    return new Promise((res, rej) => {
        res(smth);
    });
 }`
```

and CronJob takes parameter onTick which `The function to fire at the specified time`.

example from docs:

```
`const cron = require('cron');
 var job1 = new cron.CronJob({
     cronTime: '* * * * *',
     onTick: function() { // How to pass my promise?
         console.log('job 1 ticked');
     },
     start: false,
     timeZone: 'America/Los_Angeles'
 });`
```

Again how can I pass promise func to onTick parameter? Or maybe there is another solution for the issue?

2) Should I install any package to setting timeZone?
If I set timeZone to "Asia/Baku", will it works?

Comment: You can do `onTick: a`, if that's what you want.

Comment: but if promise take an argument? or how can I handle resolved promise there?

Answer (score 0):

`onTick` method takes a function only. You can assign it to a function with in-turn calls your promise. Something like :

```
onTick: PromiseRunner
```

where `PromiseRunner` is the function in which you invoke the promise.

To handle the promise, you need to do it inside the `PromiseRunner` function using [Promise chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises#Chaining).

You can't pass any argument to the `onTick` function (or to the promise), but you can use `context` property to provide the context in which you want the function to run.